# Add different flex direction with nth-child()

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to style posts to be different with `nth-child()`, one post to have one flex direction, and second other, but somehow I can't achieve what I want. This is my css:

```
.front-page-posts {
    display: flex;
    height: 620px;
    background: black;
}

.fp-image img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
.fp-title {
    margin: auto;
}
.front-page-posts:nth-child(2n+0) {    
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

And this is targeted markup from my wp theme:

```
<article id="post-34" class="post-34 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-front-page">
   <div class="front-page-posts">
     <div class="fp-title">
         <h1 class="entry-title">Marketeers with a passion for people.</h1>     
     </div>
     <div class="fp-image">
         <img src="two-guys.jpg">       
     </div>
   </div><!-- .entry-header -->
</article>
```

So, how can I achieve to one post with image and title go to one direction, and second to the other ?

Comment: Use `even` and `odd`  for repetitive alternating styling - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Example_selectors)

Comment: But the `nth-child(2n+0)`, or `nth-child(2n)`, does select every 2nd, starting from the 2nd (as `even` also does), so how is it not working for you?

Comment: Can you post an HTML example where there is more than an front page element, so that we can really check the issue ?

Comment: Knowing the way WordPress typically works (though your theme could have changed this), you are probably looking for: `article.type-post:nth-child(2n+0) .front-page-posts {flex-direction: row-reverse;}`

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, yes, yes....thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome!  :)  I just posted that as an answer with a bit more explanation.  Let me know if it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, because WordPress repeats the `article` and not the `.front-page-posts`, this is the code you will have to use:

```
article.type-post:nth-child(2n+0) .front-page-posts {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Your HTML will look something like this, so you have to iterate the CSS on the article instead of the the `.front-page-posts` div, which will always by the nth-first-child.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article id="post-34" class="post-34 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-front-page">
       <div class="front-page-posts">
         <div class="fp-title">
             <h1 class="entry-title">Marketeers with a passion for people.</h1>     
         </div>
         <div class="fp-image">
             <img src="two-guys.jpg">       
         </div>
       </div><!-- .entry-header -->
    </article>
    <article id="post-34" class="post-34 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-front-page">
       <div class="front-page-posts">
         <div class="fp-title">
             <h1 class="entry-title">Marketeers with a passion for people.</h1>     
         </div>
         <div class="fp-image">
             <img src="two-guys.jpg">       
         </div>
       </div><!-- .entry-header -->
    </article>
</div>
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  If not, leave a comment and I'll try to clarify a bit more.